# ブラウザからnode.jsが動かせない

Tags: node.js

ブラウザからserverサイドとしてのJSを動かしたいのですが、ファイル読み込み先のJSファイルがそのまま返ってきてしまいます。PHPをApacheで動かすときはそれ用のモジュールの読み込みをhttpd.confに書きましたが、そのような設定が必要かと思い調べてみましたが、特に情報が無く困っています。以下今やっている手順です。

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req, res){
  if(req.url === "/js/index.js"){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function(err, data){
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/javascript', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end(); 
    })
  }
})

server.listen(port, hostname)
```

---

```
forever start server.js
```

---

```
localhost:3000/js/index.js #ブラウザからアクセス
```

---

Answer (score 0):

ソース内でreadFileでjavascriptファイルの中身をとってきて
text/javascript
としてヘッダーを返しています。
そのためブラウザもヘッダーでtext/javascriptって返しているし、中身もJavascriptだから通常のWebサービスのようにJSファイルとして受け取っているのかと思います

ルーティングの基本としてはif文内に書きたい処理を書けばいいと思います。

```
  if(req.url === "/js/index.js"){
    //ここに書きたい処理を書いてしまえばいいと思います。
  }
```

あとはNodeJS ルーティングで調べればいろいろ出てくるとは思いますが、
[Express](http://expressjs.com/)を利用することが多いと思います。こちらも参考にしつつ試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。勘違いしていましたが、解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

件名から判断して回答しますが。。
ブラウザ上で、/js/index.jsの内容が表示されるのであれば
mode.jsは動いてます。（ポート3000で待ち受けて動いているので）

なぜ、内容が表示されるかは。。

```
   res.write(data);
```

しているので、そのまま表示されてるだけです。（実装された通りです）

単純にindex.jsを動かしたいのであれば、サーバーサイドのNode.jsではなく
普通にNode.jsでやってみてはいかがでしょうか。
（index.js内容も不明ですので、この時点で一旦回答します）

Comment: ありがとうございます。勘違いしていましたが、解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

勘違いでした。fs.readFileでファイルを読んでtext/javascriptとして返すことはブラウザでjsを読めるようにして返すことで、node.jsを実行してその結果を得たいのであればrequire('/js/index.js')するだけでした。